# What is this bonus i get from a class change?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

In STory Mode of Etrian Odyssey Untold, I was fiddling with Class Changing just to see what classes i could change into and it talked about some bonus i would get which i can't really tell what it is since my level drops when i do (and thus unable to see any stat bonus).

So what is this bonus and would i get it if i changed class to the same class i was before? (ie. Highlander -> Highlander)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retiring does the following:

1.) Your current explorer disappears.

2.) You gain a new explorer at half the level of the Retired one.

3.) The new explorer can be reclassed.

4.) The new explorer gains bonuses to stats and skill points based on how high the original explorer's level was.

Changing Class does the following:

1.) Your current explorer is retained.

2.) Your current explorer's level is reduced to half of what it was orginally.

3.) Your current explorer can be reclassed.

4.) Your current explorer gains bonuses to stats and skill points based on how high your original level was (these bonuses are identical to Retiring).

**5.) Your character's portrait and Stat growth are the same as the original class.**

Note the bold. This means a Highlander who reclasses to an Alchemist will still have piss-poor Tec growth, while a Hexer who reclasses to a Ronin will still have piss-poor Str growth.

Also, if you reclass at 70, then level to 70 and reclass again, the bonus doesn't stack. You'd have to reclass at a higher level to get the bonus higher.